# Multiplayer GameObject design

Tags: c++, object-oriented, c++11, game, pointers

I created a really basic game class. A game has `GameObject` instances, which currently have a position only.

This code is running on the client, and in each loop iteration:

- The client receives the updates from the server
- It executes the received events
- The client updates the game state

I created a map to store game objects. The reason why I chose `std::map` is because I need to access game objects by their index, to update them. And sometimes an object may be deleted, so there would be holes in the `std::vector` if I would use it.

I created an `Updateable` class, so when I execute events, and one of them is affected by the properties of the other objects, then the execution order does not matter (it may be parallelized later).

The classes were originally in separate files, and have header files and a namespace too. I just put it together, to show them:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <map>

/* Vec2 struct */
struct Vec2 {
    double x;
    double y;

    Vec2() {
        x=0.0;
        y=0.0;
    }

    Vec2(double x, double y) : 
        x(x),
        y(y)
    {}

    friend Vec2 operator+(const Vec2 &v1, const Vec2 &v2) {
        return Vec2(v1.x+v2.x, v1.y + v2.y);
    }
};

/* Updateable class */
template<class T>
class Updateable {

    T current;
    T next;

public:

    void setNext(T val) {
        next = val;
    }

    T getCurrent() const {
        return current;
    }

    T getNext() const {
        return next;
    }

    void update() {
        current = next;
        next = T();
    }

};

/* GameObj class */
class GameObj {

    const int obj_id;

public:

    Updateable<Vec2> position;

    GameObj(int obj_id) : obj_id(obj_id) {

    }

    virtual ~GameObj() {}

};

/* Event class */
class Game;

class Event {
public:

    virtual void do_event(Game* game) const = 0;

    virtual ~Event() {}

};

/* Game class */
class Game {

    std::queue<Event*> events;

    std::map<int, GameObj*> objects;


public:

    GameObj* findObj(int id) {
        auto it = objects.find(id);
        if ( it != objects.end() ) {
            return it->second;
        }
        return nullptr;
    }

    GameObj* addObj(int id) {
        GameObj* obj = new GameObj(id);
        auto it = objects.find(id);
        if ( it != objects.end() ) {
            delete it->second;
            it->second = obj;
        } else {
            objects[id] = obj;
        }
        return obj;
    }

    void addEvent(Event* event) {
        events.push(event);
    }

    void update() {

        // process events
        while(!events.empty()) {
            Event* event = events.front();

            event->do_event(this);

            events.pop();
            delete event;
        }

        // update objects
        for(auto iterator = objects.begin(); iterator != objects.end(); iterator++) {
            iterator->second->position.update();
        }

    }

    ~Game() {

        while(!events.empty()) {
            Event* event = events.front();
            events.pop();
            delete event;
        }

        for(auto iterator = objects.begin(); iterator != objects.end(); iterator++) {
            delete iterator->second;
        }

        objects.clear();

    }

};

/* MoveObjEvent class */
class MoveObjEvent : public Event {

    const int obj_id;
    const Vec2 move_vec;

public:

    MoveObjEvent(int obj_id, Vec2 move_vec) :
        obj_id(obj_id),
        move_vec(move_vec)
    {}

    virtual void do_event(Game* game) const override {

        GameObj* obj = game->findObj(obj_id);

        if(obj != nullptr) {
            obj->position.setNext(obj->position.getNext() + move_vec);
        }

    }

};

/* CreateObjEvent class */
class CreateObjEvent : public Event {

    const int obj_id;

public:
    CreateObjEvent(int obj_id) :
        obj_id(obj_id)
    {}

    virtual void do_event(Game* game) const override {
        game->addObj(obj_id);
    }

};

int main() {

    // create a game object
    Game game;

    /*
     * Example of one iteration:
     */

    // recive events from server
    game.addEvent(new CreateObjEvent(1));
    game.addEvent(new MoveObjEvent(1, Vec2(5, 6)));

    // update game
    game.update();

    /*
     * One iteration ends here
     */

    // test
    std::cout << game.findObj(1)->position.getCurrent().x << std::endl;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: I have updated my answer and rolled back the rollback to make the rolled rollback valid after making the answer previously invalidated by rolled back answer valid after the rolled back rollback. :)

Answer (score 5):

## Don't roll your own math libraries

When making a game you will need a lot of math, rolling your own is time consuming and error prone and unless you've got a very strong background in computational mathematics likely to be slower than using a library.

Personally I often use [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page).

## Use default constructors to reduce code

You can replace this:

```
double x;
double y;

Vec2() {
    x=0.0;
    y=0.0;
}

Vec2(double x, double y) : 
    x(x),
    y(y)
{}
```

by this with the exact same functionality:

```
double x = 0.0;
double y = 0.0;

Vec2() = default;

Vec2(double x, double y) 
  : x(x), y(y)
{}
```

If you are going to roll your own math you need to provide all the operators for vectors. When implementing operators there are certain tricks that you can use to reduce code. For example you can implement all the relational operators (not that you would for a vector, just showing a concept) like this:

```
bool opeartor < (const T& rhs) const {
    // Implement only this
}

bool operator > (const T& rhs) const {
   return rhs < *this; // Implement using '<'
} 

bool operator <= (const T& rhs) const {
   return !(rhs  < *this); // Implement using '<'
}

bool operator >= (const T& rhs) const {
   return !(*this  < rhs); // Implement using '<'
}
```

And for example you can implement addition like this:

```
T& operator += (const T& rhs){
    // Implement this
}

T operator + (const T& rhs) const {
    T ans(*this);
    ans += rhs; // Implement using copy ctor and '+='
    return ans;
}
```

Once you realise the above you can use the [Barton-Nackman trick](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Barton%E2%80%93Nackman_trick) for making all these operators easy to implement in many classes.

## Using raw pointers is bad

Using raw pointers is considered bad practice in modern C++. For some interesting reading [check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6675651/when-should-i-use-raw-pointers-over-smart-pointers).

By using smart pointers (such as [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) since C++11) your code would simplify as you would no longer have to care about calling `delete` at various points so cleanup would be easier and `add` would simplify too.

## Use `std::unordered_map`

The standard library `std::map` is implemented using a tree (typically a [Red-Black tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red%E2%80%93black_tree). As such it has logarithmic insertion, lookup and removal. But whats worse than the logarithmic time complexity is that it is a tree and traversing a tree is prone to cache misses which will severely impact your performance.

On the other hand [`std::unordered_map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map) has (amortised) constant time lookup, insertion and removal which is faster and because it has to be implemented using a [Hash Table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table)  the elements will be in a more or less contiguous memory region making your CPU cache perform better.

## Use enhanced `for` loops

Replace this kind of code:

```
    // update objects
    for(auto iterator = objects.begin(); iterator != objects.end(); iterator++) {
        iterator->second->position.update();
    }
```

with this:

```
    // update objects
    for(auto& object : objects) {
        object.second->position.update();
    }
```

## Use of white space

You have a lot of randomly added line breaks, this makes your code difficult to read because I have to scroll a lot. Please keep your code tidy.

## Don't do unnecessary work

For example in your `Game` destructor you do this:

```
~Game() {

    while(!events.empty()) {
        Event* event = events.front();
        events.pop();
        delete event;
    }

    for(auto iterator = objects.begin(); iterator != objects.end(); iterator++) {
        delete iterator->second;
    }

    objects.clear();

}
```

If you were using `std::shared_ptr` you could replace all of the above by:

```
~Game() = default;
```

because both the `queue` and `objects`'s destructors will clear them and if each of them only contain objects that clean up them selves like `std::shared_ptr` then you don't need to do anything.

I will refrain from reviewing high level concepts of the implementation because I think it is too hard get an overview of your code due to how it is formatted.

Comment: "I will refrain from reviewing high level concepts of the implementation" That breaks my little heart :( But thank you for the suggestions, I find them useful

Comment: @Iter_Ator I'm sorry but as it is right now it's too much work for me. Clean it up, incorporate the feedback and post a new question and I can have a look.

Comment: @IterAtor For formatting your code, I recommend looking into [clang-format](http://clang.llvm.org/get_started.html) which will make it much easier to maintain a consistent style.

Answer (score 4):

---

General Consideration:

Since I saw `nullptr` and `auto` I think you are able to use C++11:
For this you should think about using the STL smart-pointer from . This would lead to safer and clearer code. For example if you change `addEvent(Event*)` to `addEvent(std::unique_ptr<Event> &&)` it would be clear that Game will take the ownership of the event.

It would also make all calls for `delete` unnecessary and would prevent you from forgetting one. And last but not least when using smart_pointer your code would be more exception safe.

---

Coding style:

Vec2:

Since Vec2 is a struct the members are public by default. Thus it makes no sense to declare the operator+ as a friend because friend means that the operator can acces [private member](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/friend) which you do not have.
It is also sometimes stated that if you have any methods on a class / struct it would be better to make all members private.

GameObj:

The obj_id is not used, so you can delete it.

It would be better design to make the `position` private and let the GameObj have an update() method by itself. 
One could also suggest to delete the class since it does not do anything. When you use it you identify the Object by an external saved id (in the map) and only call update on the position. Why not change `std::map<int, GameObj*> objects;` to `std::map<int, Updateable<Vec2>> objects;`?

Game:

Use the [range-for](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/range-for) to make code simpler, thus

```
for(auto iterator = objects.begin(); iterator != objects.end(); iterator++) {
    iterator->second->position.update();
}
```

can be changed to

```
for(auto obj : objects){
    obj->position.update();
}
```

I hope these little things are helpfull.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestions. The reason why I created `GameObj`, is that it will contain later more, not just it's position ( rotation/velocity/health/etc... )

Answer (score 3):

Here are some things that may help you improve your code.

### Every function must have a declared return type

In modern C++, every function must have a declared return type, even if that return type is simply `void`.  In this code, `addEvent` and `update` are missing return types.

### Rethink your classes

The difference between the `GameObj` class and the `Updateable` templated class and the `Vec2` class is very slight.  Do you really need all of those different classes and templates or might they be collapsed into a simpler hierarchy?  I find that keeping classes concrete and large initially, and only refactoring when/if specializations or compositions/derivations become necessary later on keeps things as simple as practical for as long as practical.  If the *only* use of the `Updateable` class is within the `GameObj` class, I'd say that it's highly likely that you don't need both.

### Rethink your interfaces

The `GameObj` class is named and constructed in a way that strongly hints at the existence of more derived classes either now or in the future.  Given that, the `addObj` function, which takes an `id` and returns a `GameObj *` makes little sense.  Better would be to require that the caller passes a `GameObj` pointer in, and that the object `id` is assigned either when the object is created or assigned when the object is stored within the `map`.

### Be clear about object ownership

It appears that when an `Event` is processed, that it's also deleted, so the implication is that the `Game` class owns the objects.  However, the situation is not so clear for `objects`.  Be explicit and clear about which thing owns which objects so that it's clear when they're created and destroyed.  Also consider `std::shared_ptr` or `std::unique_ptr` as alternative to raw pointers.

### Think carefully about references vs. pointers

What should happen if `nullptr` is passed in as an argument tothe `MoveObjEvent::do_event()` function?  Probably not a segfault, but that's likely what would happen at the moment. Also, what should happen if a `nullptr` is passed to the `Game::addEvent` routine?  If you pass a pointer, you should probably be checking for `nullptr`; if you don't check for `nullptr`, you probably should be passing a reference rather than a pointer.

### Omit `return 0`

When a C or C++ program reaches the end of `main` the compiler will automatically generate code to return 0, so there is no need to put `return 0;` explicitly at the end of `main`.

**Note:** when I make this suggestion, it's almost invariably followed by one of two kinds of comments:  "I didn't know that." or "That's bad advice!"  My rationale is that it's safe and useful to rely on compiler behavior explicitly supported by the standard.  For C, since C99; see ISO/IEC 9899:1999 section 5.1.2.2.3:

> [...] a return from the initial call to the `main` function is equivalent to calling the `exit` function with the value returned by the `main` function as its argument; reaching the `}` that terminates the `main` function returns a value of 0.

For C++, since the first standard in 1998; see ISO/IEC 14882:1998 section 3.6.1:

> If control reaches the end of main without encountering a return statement, the effect is that of executing return 0;

All versions of both standards since then (C99 and C++98) have maintained the same idea.  We rely on automatically generated member functions in C++, and few people write explicit `return;` statements at the end of a `void` function.  Reasons against omitting seem to boil down to ["it looks weird"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2581993/what-the-reasons-for-against-returning-0-from-main-in-iso-c/2582015#2582015).  If, like me, you're curious about the rationale for the change to the C standard [read this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31394171/what-was-the-rationale-for-making-return-0-at-the-end-of-main-optional).  Also note that in the early 1990s this was considered "sloppy practice" because it was undefined behavior (although widely supported) at the time.

So I advocate omitting it; others disagree (often vehemently!)  In any case, if you encounter code that omits it, you'll know that it's explicitly supported by the standard and you'll know what it means.

Comment: I would advise against keeping classes large because that is a slippery slope to a [god object](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/God_object) and makes it very easy to break [SRP](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). Not to mention that merging updatable into game object is the wrong abstraction. I can envision updatable being expanded to implement "easing" of remote state to incoming state in a network game. And how it may be specialized for different types. I see it as a wrapped type.

Comment: @EmilyL. Your comment has some merit, but it's not what I was suggesting. Generally, some some use a top-down design approach. Others prefer a more agile approach that emphasizes refactoring and an evolutionary approach. Both processes can be done badly or abused, but when done well, in my experience, they tend to converge on a similar end result.